# Reinterpreting suitably aligned pointers to object with declared type

Tags: c, language-lawyer, type-punning

The Standard allows us to cast pointers to object type to each other if they are suitably aligned. `6.3.2.3(p7)`:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned68) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

The Standard allows us to copy object representation into `char[sizeof(the_object_type)]` `6.2.6.1(p4)`:

> The value may be copied into an object of type unsigned char [n]
>   (e.g., by memcpy); the resulting set of bytes is called the object
>   representation of the value.

Also, The Standard explicitly states that

> Two values (other than NaNs) with the same object representation
>   compare equal, but values that compare equal may have different object
>   representations.

Consider the following code:

```
struct contains_64_t{
    uint64_t value;
};

int main(int args, const char *argv[]){
    _Alignas(struct contains_64_t) 
        char buf_2_64t[2 * sizeof(struct contains_64_t)];
    struct contains_64_t c64_1;
    c64_1.value = 1;
    struct contains_64_t c64_2;
    c64_2.value = 2;
    memcpy(buf_2_64t, &c64_1, sizeof(c64_1));
    memcpy(buf_2_64t + sizeof(c64_1), &c64_2, sizeof(c64_2));

    //suitably aligned, ok
    struct contains_64_t *c64_ptr = (struct contains_64_t*) buf_2_64t; 
    printf("Value %"PRIu64"\n", c64_ptr -> value);
}
```

***QUESTION:*** Is it pedantic to write code like this? If no, what kind of problem we may run into if doing so?

From what I see,

we can cast `char*` to `struct contains_64_t` since it is suitably aligned. But the problem is that the declared type of `buf` is `char[2 * sizeof(struct contains_64_t)]`. So formally speaking we cannot access the `buf` through an lvalue of type `struct contains_64_t *`.

But that would be strange since we have suitably aligned pointer and literally identical object representation. Surely we could declare `struct contains_64_t buf[2];`, but the solution would not work in case of `struct` containing ***variably length array***

UPD: Would doing such buffer alignment be enough if we assume we are compiling with GCC?

Comment: Alignment is not the potential UB here, by anti-aliasing is a concern perhaps with `struct contains_64_t *c64_ptr = (struct contains_64_t*) buf_2_64t;`.  `printf("Value = %lu\n", c64_ptr -> value);` is certainly UB with 32-bit `long`.

Comment: @chux Why is casting to a suitably aligned pointer UB? Or you mean UB is caused by incorrect use of `printf`? Fixed.

Comment: Some 1)  _casting_ is not the UB concern, [anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) UB may apply here.  2) `%lu` is for `unsigned long`, not necessarily `uint64_t`.

Comment: @chux Agree with `2)`. Replaced it with `PRIu64` defined in `inttypes.h`.

Comment: @chux Anyway if we do not align the pointer to stack-allocated buffer we cannot convert it. So UB will also come at `struct contains_64_t *c64_ptr = (struct contains_64_t*) buf_2_64t;` otherwise the Standard permits such convertation at `6.2.3.2(p7)`.

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy()`'s look OK.

`c64_ptr -> value` is UB.

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of
>   the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the
>   effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a
>   qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned
>   types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>   subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

Look up `compatible` in the standard to complete the picture.